# How can I add a chrome-like focus rectangle to a wpf control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

There are a lot of questions on how to remove focus rectangles, but I want them to always show, just like Chrome/Safari does.  I think I want to use an adorner so as not to interfere with existing styles that a control has, but I've never used them and can't find any examples on how to do what I want.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit: The input box here has a blue border when focused

[image: Input box has blue border when focused]

Comment: What "focus rectangle" are you referring to ? post a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect is called "outer glow"; once you know that, google turns up tons of stuff.  I found this works pretty well:

```
        <DropShadowEffect x:Key="SelectionGlow" BlurRadius="3" ShadowDepth="0" Color="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" Direction="0" />

        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource SelectionGlow}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

A couple things about this solution:

1. It doesn't disable the focus rectangle on buttons, etc
2. I'm not sure if performance is an issue- there is (was?) problems with bitmap effect rendering.  I'm not sure if that applies anymore, or if this qualifies as a bitmap effect.  It's only used on the focused element, so it can't be too bad.